# how to unittest a sqldatareader?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am wondering how to unittest a SqlDataReader?

class MyClass has GetRows method:

```
   public static SqlDataReader GetRows()
    {
           SqlDataReader reader = null;
           DataSet dst = new DataSet();
           SqlCommand cmd = null;

           //more code here
    }
```

My unittest:

```
[Test]
public void Generator_GetFeedRowsFromDB()
{
            SqlDataReader dr = MyClass.GetRows();
            var test= dr;

            //turns out the reader dr is closed at this point : (
}
```

How can I create a unit test for the datareader ? Should I use a different class to retrieve my rows?

Comment: Question is, why do you want to UT `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: That "more code here" part is important in answering your question. Also.. what exactly are you testing?